# center align icons in android BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview

I am trying out newly released [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) from android support library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0`

My assumption was menu icons will be center_vertial aligned if I don't setup menu titles but thats not happening. Below is sample screenshot.

[image]

Can someone point me in correct direction if its possible at all without rolling down and custom view? I am targeting following output.

[image]

Comment: Please Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183239/remove-bottomnavigationview-labels/40188794#40188794. I remove it using reflection.

Comment: @Sanf0rd Thanks a lot for answer! but at this moment I am not looking to use reflection approach. I think I will have to live with titles for now.

Comment: =/. in this first releasse it is not possible. Can I answer this?

Comment: @Sanf0rd I have already up voted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's quite late, but you can add `app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"` to your `BottomNavigationView` tag

Answer (score 2):

You can use `app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"` to hide the labels this way the icons will be aligned to center

Answer (score 1):

The space below your images is the titles' space (Empty TextView). I believe that they currently don't support an image without a text. (`MenuItem` must have a title, else it throws an error in xml).

Comment: I feel you explanation qualifies more of a comment than answer :).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14795909)

Comment: @demongolem Thank you for your review, I will take that into consideration next time I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:paddingTop="15dp"` and use `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"` instead of `app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"`

Or you can use Libs like https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx