# Remove BottomNavigationView labels

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, bottomnavigationview

Google released new support library v25 with BottomNavigationView

[image]

is there any way to remove items labels ?

Comment: Did you try removing the `title`s from the menu `<item>`s?

Comment: After removing titles there is extra padding below icons. Adding `layout_marginBottom="-16dp"` will remove this padding but will make all the view smaller.

Comment: You can instead of setting margin, set custom height and add some extra padding to the top. In that way you can center the icons.

Comment: I just fixed it like this:
`android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"`

This prevents the bar from getting smaller

Answer (score 279, accepted):

I hope I am not too late to the party here.

But as of Design Support Library 28.0.0-alpha1
you can use the property

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

[image: BottomNavigationView without labels]

you can use other values "auto", "labeled" and "selected" as well.

Comment: which support library? v7 or design?

Comment: design support library 28.0.0

Comment: In what class do you write this in?

Comment: @Explorex This is android's bottom navigation view and the attributes I mentioned are xml attributes of the said class used in the said view's xml tag.
you can use it in code too https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/LabelVisibilityMode

Comment: can we change position of text and icon ? i want texts besides icon

Answer (score 22):

Would you want to this style ?

[image]

[image]

If so, I recommend you try [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx).

Comment: I dont like this library. it makes icon position changed when clicked and no way to make the icon position fixed when clicked.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately this first version of BottomNavigationView came with a lot of limitations. And for now you can't remove the titles just using the support design API. So to solve this limitation while google doesn't implement it, you can do (using reflection):

**1. Set the titles empty in from bottom_navigation_menu.xml file.**

**2. Extends the BottomNavigationView:**

```
    public class MyBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationView {

      public MyBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          centerMenuIcon();
      }

      private void centerMenuIcon() {
          BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = getBottomMenuView();

          if (menuView != null) {
              for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView menuItemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);

                AppCompatImageView icon = (AppCompatImageView) menuItemView.getChildAt(0);

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

                menuItemView.setShiftingMode(true);
              }
          }
      }

      private BottomNavigationMenuView getBottomMenuView() {
          Object menuView = null;
          try {
              Field field = BottomNavigationView.class.getDeclaredField("mMenuView");
              field.setAccessible(true);
              menuView = field.get(this);
          } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return (BottomNavigationMenuView) menuView;
      }
    }
```

**3. Add to the layout.xml this customView**

For more details I have implemented this on [Github](https://github.com/DavidSanf0rd/BottomNavigationViewSample)

Comment: No need to use reflection, you can get each `BottomNavigationItemView` by calling `findViewById()` with the menu items ids (just like @NikolaDespotoski is doing in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234361/2352699)).

Comment: They support removing labels now `app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"`

Answer (score 12):

**1.** Set `android:title="";` in **menu/abc.xml**

**2.** Create the below helper class which is using reflection

```
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                item.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 0);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**3.** In your main activity, add these lines:

```
mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(mBottomNav);
```

Answer (score 11):

Reflectionless approach:

```
private void removeTextLabel(@NonNull BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView, @IdRes int menuItemId) {
    View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(menuItemId);
    if (view == null) return;
    if (view instanceof MenuView.ItemView) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        int padding = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                padding = v.getHeight();
                viewGroup.removeViewAt(i);
            }
        }
        viewGroup.setPadding(view.getPaddingLeft(), (viewGroup.getPaddingTop() + padding) / 2, view.getPaddingRight(), view.getPaddingBottom());
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if I want to remove icon instead of the text

Comment: How can I call this in the main activity where the default BottomNavigation code already exists? @NikolaDespotoski

Comment: @TiagoIB just make the method static and move it to some other class. Or keep it private and call it with arguments specified.

Comment: Excuse me, but how could I insert it in my code?http://prntscr.com/he03j7 @NikolaDespotoski

Answer (score 5):

This is a temporary fix. Just add: `app:itemTextColor="@android:color/transparent"` That'll make it whatever the background color is, appearing disabled. It does make the icon look elevated.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to remove both the [shift animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode) and the labels and none of the solutions here worked well for me, so here's the one I built based on everything I learned here:

```
public void removeLabels(@IdRes int... menuItemIds) {
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override public boolean onPreDraw() {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

            // this only needs to be calculated once for an unchecked item, it'll be the same value for all items
            ViewGroup uncheckedItem = findFirstUncheckedItem(menuItemIds);
            View icon = uncheckedItem.getChildAt(0);
            int iconTopMargin = ((LayoutParams) uncheckedItem.getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams()).topMargin;
            int desiredTopMargin = (uncheckedItem.getHeight() - uncheckedItem.getChildAt(0).getHeight()) / 2;
            int itemTopPadding = desiredTopMargin - iconTopMargin;

            for (int id : menuItemIds) {
                ViewGroup item = findViewById(id);
                // remove the label
                item.removeViewAt(1);
                // and then center the icon
                item.setPadding(item.getPaddingLeft(), itemTopPadding, item.getPaddingRight(),
                        item.getPaddingBottom());
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private ViewGroup findFirstUncheckedItem(@IdRes int... menuItemIds) {
    BottomNavigationItemView item = findViewById(menuItemIds[0]);
    int i = 1;
    while (item.getItemData().isChecked()) {
        item = findViewById(menuItemIds[i++]);
    }
    return item;
}
```

Just add this method to your custom `BottomNavigationView` and call it passing the ids of the menu items.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to implement it by yourself as [sanf0rd gave in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40188794/1104612). But `AppCompatImageView` is not working for me. I've changed it to `ImageView`. And changed `getChildAt` to `findViewById`.

Also I hide all labels of unselected items.

```
private void centerMenuIcon() {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = getBottomMenuView();
    if (menuView != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView menuItemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            TextView smallText = (TextView) menuItemView.findViewById(R.id.smallLabel);
            smallText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //TextView largeText = (TextView) menuItemView.findViewById(R.id.largeLabel);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) menuItemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            menuItemView.setShiftingMode(true);
        }
    }
}
```