# Android BottomNavigationView disable icon title

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to create Bottom navigation view in android without a title, but I'm unable to hide the title. Also, I need to active and inactive icon colour for Bottom navigation view.

Expected design
[image]

Current design
[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/bottom_nav_colour"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    design:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

**bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:title="@string/menu_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_add"
        android:title="@string/menu_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_wishlist"
        android:title="@string/menu_wishlist"
        android:icon="@drawable/wishlist"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_account"
        android:title="@string/menu_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/account" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I think this link be helepful  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183239/remove-bottomnavigationview-labels

Comment: @Kintanpatel The above link did not work out

Comment: Try to add this line in all your menu file android:title=""   just make a blank title

Comment: This will keep blank space at the bottom. And the icon will not appear in center

Comment: check out my answer below [view solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943416/remove-bottom-navigation-view-text-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

In the latest support library for BottomNavigationView you can use [labelVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/LabelVisibilityMode)

Answer (score -1):

You can create selector for icons.

selector_home_icon.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="drawable/home" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="drawable/home_disabled"/>
</selector>
```

Set this selector as icon drawable

bottom_navigation.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:title="@string/menu_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/selector_home_icon" />

     .......

</menu>
```

Comment: use state_checked="true" instead of state_selected

Comment: He's using Bottom Navigation not TabLayout!