# Remove bottom navigation view text in android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I use bottom navigation view for my app and want to remove the text under the icon. I looked for it on the internet but still can't find the solution. Did anyone use to deal with this please give me your solution.

[image]

All i want is like this:

[image]

My code here:
The main layout contain a recyclerview and a bottomnavigationview:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="8.5"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:background="@color/whiteColor"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the bottomnavigation menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_music"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Save"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_me"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Me"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And in MainActivity:

```
    mBottomBar = (BottomNavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);
    disableShiftMode(mBottomBar);

    public void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            item.setShiftingMode(false);
            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("Luan", "Unable to get shift mode field");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("Luan", "Unable to change value of shift mode");
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens in your current code post that please also if possible post relevant code

Comment: I dont see any text. What do you mean

Comment: i mean all i want look like in the second picture. i edited my post.

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: For this you can create a custom layout mean take LinearLayout(Horizontal) and add 5 images into it and give equal weight to all Images.

Comment: i added my code. please take a look at it

Comment: @LuanSiHo did you find the solution?

Comment: @MNFS i still don't find the solution

Comment: @LuanSiHo me too, i recommend you change with ButtonBarLayout or LinearLayout that's the simple way

Comment: please add this single line: app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" inside BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

set "app:labelVisibilityMode"    with   "unlabeled"

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
```

Comment: This answer is seriously underrated. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Remove titles in menu items.Then apply padding top to bottomnavigationview like below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
android:tittle=""
android:enabled="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
android:tittle=""
android:enabled="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
android:id="@+id/action_music"
android:tittle=""
android:enabled="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
android:id="@+id/action_me"
android:tittle=""
android:enabled="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

In Bottom navigation view

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
```

Comment: add android:tittle=""

Comment: Of course, showAsAction, it was bugging me so much that neither the icon nor the text was centred... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add this in your BottomNavigationView and the title and annoying animation is gone `app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"`

Answer (score -1):

I find the solutions please check the below small changes.

**First of all change in bottomnavigation menu xml:**

Updated xml:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_music"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_me"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```