# bottom navigation menu icon item

Tags: java, android, menu, bottomnavigationview

Hi I am developing an application using

android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView. The menu consists of 3 elements with text and icon. How do I create three elements with only icons and without text?

Here the menu code

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contatti"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/contatti"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/home"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notifiche"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/notifiche"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

`

Comment: Look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40188794/2717821

Answer (score 0):

Remove the android:title="@string/notifiche"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_contatti"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_home"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_notifiche"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
        </menu>
```

and make sure you make you set the width and hight like this android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

```
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/navigation_ID"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@color/navigationBG"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.48"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_natigation_bar" />
```