# I need to hide title of items in bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-support-design

I create bottom navigation bar  and i need to hide title and show icons only but when i write title with empty string there is big space between icon and bottom it just replace string with empty string and i make many search but i don't found solutions so any help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.easyschools.student.HomeActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
 </FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
        android:icon="@drawable/msg_icon"
        android:title=""/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:title=""
        android:checked="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notify"
        android:icon="@drawable/notify_icon"
        android:title=""/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_my_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:title=""/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183239/remove-bottomnavigationview-labels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183239/remove-bottomnavigationview-labels Try here!

Answer (score 16):

Starting from support library `28.0.0-alpha1`, you can use:

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

to hide title and

```
app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
```

add:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to disable shift mode to your `BottomNavigationView` in xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use following property of BottomNavigationView:

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

also include following line in you layout:

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

For reference you can use following link:
https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/remove-bottom-navigation-view-title-in-android.php

Answer (score 0):

The `BottomNavigationView` have a lot of limitations.

You can set the title with an empty `String` `""` for example but I recommend you to use a library for enhancing the bottom navigation bar easily.

You can try this one : https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx

Comment: How to change the icon if I select another tab? Mine cannot change